# Disabling routes in angular js + laravel project

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have a laravel application which uses angular js as the front end. There I need to disable this route. `appo.dev/` which means the root path of the application. How can I disable that path only. Here I need to access other routes such as `appo.dev/progess`. I tried the following way in routes.php file. It's better if I can find a solution with this code.

```
Route::any('{path?}', function () {
   return view("appo_app");
})->where("path", ".+")
->whereNotIn("path", "appo.dev/");
```

Above without whereNotIn clause it will work for all the routes. So I am thinking a way to disable only that particular route via wherenotin clause. Or is there a better wild card character? Anyone knows how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe without what you want is like the root route did not exist, you can try this.
And it will return an error 404. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

I assume that appo.dev is the domain.

```
Route::any('/', function () {
    abort(404);
});

Route::any('{path?}', function () {
   return view("appo_app");
})->where("path", ".+");
```

If it were not the domain, maybe this will help you.

```
Route::any('appo.dev', function () {
    abort(404);
});

Route::any('appo.dev/{path?}', function () {
   return view("appo_app");
})->where("path", ".+");
```

I hope it helps you. A cordial greeting.

Comment: @MCooper,  I'm glad I could help you. Have a nice day.